# Every $R$-module is an iterated colimit of $R$

Tags: category-theory, modules, solution-verification, limits-colimits

Let $R$ be a commutative algebra over a field $k$. My problem set asks me to

> Show that every $R$-module is an iterated colimit of $R$.

**My idea**

Let $A$ be a free $R$-module with basis $M$, and let $\pi :A \to M$ be the R-module homomorphism taking each basis element to the corresponding element of $M$. Clearly $A$ is surjective, so $M \cong A/\ker \pi$.

It is easy to see that $A$ is a coproduct of $\lvert M \rvert$ copies of $R$, so $A$ is certainly a colimit of $R$.

We would then like to show that $M$ is a colimit of $A$. This is where I get less confident. Let $U \subseteq A \times A$ be the subset $U = \{(a, b) \in U\times U\mid a - b\in \ker \pi\}$. It is easy to check that $U$ is a submodule of $A\times A$.

Define the maps
$$
f:U \to A, (a,b) \mapsto \pi(a),\quad
g:U\to A, (a,b) \mapsto\pi(b).
$$

Then $A/\ker \pi$ is the coequaliser of $U \rightrightarrows A$.

So we have obtained $M$ using two colimits.

**The problem**

I am not sure what is meant by an "iterated colimit". In particular, I am uneasy about the way I have defined $U$, where I have basically just prescribed exactly what I want the quotient to be. This feels potentially problematic because the diagram $U \rightrightarrows A$ is not constructed entirely as a colimit of $R$ (i.e. $A$ but not $U$ is a colimit of $R$).

I'm not sure whether this is a valid concern, especially because I don't have a precise definition of "iterated colimit".

Is my solution valid?

Comment: There is more to say in general, but regarding your solution, it is not very well written, since $U$ is a subset of $A \times A$, so how can you say it is a submodule of $A$? Anyway, to continue your thread, it is better now to take $K$ to be the kernel of our $A \to M$, and let $B$ to be $R$-module with basis $K$. Then $M$ will be the coequalizer of the zero map and thet natural map $B \to A$ (the composition of $B \to K$ with the inclusion $K \to A$).

Comment: Sorry - I meant it's a submodule of $A \times A$. I have now fixed the typo! Regarding your alternative choice of coequaliser, does that fix my issue of the diagram not being entirely a colimit of $R$? I'm not sure why it's better.

Comment: Well, my diagram is a coequalizer of two maps between two objects, each one of which is a direct sum of copies of $R$. So clearly "iterated" in some sense (like you say, one needs perhaps to make the "iterated" bit more formal, but in our description U is again a generic module, so like you say it is not clear why you fulfill the task under any reasonable definition of "iterated")

Comment: @Sasha yes that makes sense. Thank you, that was very helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An *iterated colimit* of copies of $R$ is an object that can be inductively constructed by starting from $R$ and repeatedly taking colimits (possibly infinitely many times although in this case that’s unnecessary); said another way, the subcategory of iterated colimits of copies of $R$ is the intersection of all subcategories containing $R$ and closed under colimits.

Your argument is incomplete because you haven't shown that $U$ can be expressed as an iterated colimit of copies of $R$. (In fact you don't need this; it suffices to replace $U$ with an epimorphism from a free module to $U$.)